# Javafx: common interface between Pane and Group

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, api-design

JavaFx provides two bases containers: [`Group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) and [`Pane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html).
Both provides the same method `getChildren`:

```
@Override public ObservableList<Node> getChildren() {
    return super.getChildren();
}
```

It would have been frequently useful to have a common interface between theses two classes. I frequently saw this kind of code (from `javafx.stage.PopupWindow`):

```
protected ObservableList<Node> getContent() {
    final Parent rootNode = getScene().getRoot();
    if (rootNode instanceof Group) {
        return ((Group) rootNode).getChildren();
    }

    if (rootNode instanceof Pane) {
        return ((Pane) rootNode).getChildren();
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException(
            "The content of the Popup can't be accessed");
}
```

Why the API designers did not add a common interface ?

Comment: They have a common superclass `Parent` where `getChildren()` is defined, but is `protected`. Then there is the `getChildrenUnmodifiable()` method on `Parent` which is public, but returns a read-only list of children.

Comment: @TomasMikula I know the existence of Parent, but i would expect a common interface "`Container`" allowing to add/remove child.